# Group shapes with linked cell references

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I have multiple charts and some arrow shapes (linking to certain cells on Sheet2 to show the cell's value), all placed together inside the boundaries of a single merged cell E5.

this code works when i add different shapes and even charts to the cell and then try to run the code to group them together. However i assume it doesn't seem to work for charts which reference ranges from a pivot...i may be wrong here, and it could be totally something.

```
Option Explicit

Sub doit()
    Call GroupShapes(Sheet2.Cells(5, "E"))
End Sub

Sub GroupShapes(rngChart As Range)
    Dim Shp As Shape
    Dim ShpRng As ShapeRange
    Dim ShpGrp As Variant
    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    i = 1
    With rngChart.Parent
        For Each Shp In .Shapes
            If Shp.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Row = rngChart.MergeArea.Row Then
                ReDim Preserve Arr(1 To i)
                Arr(i) = Shp.Name
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next Shp

        Set ShpRng = .Shapes.Range(Arr)

       ' Here i get "Application defined or Object defined error"
       Set ShpGrp = ShpRng.Group

       With ShpGrp
          .Name = "shp" & VBA.Replace(rngChart.Parent.Name, " ", "")
       End With
   End With
End Sub
```

If i select all the shapes and then try to group them manually or via code (as shown below), it does Group. What am i doing wrong?

```
Sub doit1()
Dim rngChart As Range

Sheet2.Activate
With Sheet2
    Set rngChart = .Cells(5, "E")
End With
Call GroupShapes1(rngChart)

End Sub

Sub GroupShapes1(rngChart As Range)
Dim Shp As Variant
Dim Arr() As Variant

With rngChart.Parent
    For Each Shp In .Shapes
        If Not Intersect(.Range(Shp.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Cells, Shp.BottomRightCell.MergeArea.Cells), rngChart) Is Nothing Then
            Shp.Select Replace:=False
        End If
    Next Shp
    Set Shp = Selection.Group
End With
End Sub
```

I want to group the shapes, without selecting them. If anyone has any idea why this is happening, kindly assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the reason the charts were not getting selected was because each chart was named the same I.e. Object13, though their ID's were different. So once I renamed each shape and chart with a unique name ( here ID would just suffice), the grouping was possible.

```
Option Explicit 

Sub doit() 
    Call GroupShapes(Sheet2.Cells(5, "E")) 
End Sub 

Sub GroupShapes(rngChart As Range) 
Dim Shp As Shape 
Dim ShpRng As ShapeRange 
Dim ShpGrp As Variant 
Dim Arr() As Variant 
Dim i As Long i = 1 

With rngChart.Parent 
    For Each Shp In .Shapes 
        If Shp.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Row = rngChart.MergeArea.Row Then 
            With Shp
                .Name = .Type & .ID
            End With

            ReDim Preserve Arr(1 To i) 
            Arr(i) = Shp.Name 
            i = i + 1 
        End If 
    Next Shp 

    Set ShpRng = .Shapes.Range(Arr) 
    Set ShpGrp = ShpRng.Group 

    With ShpGrp 
        .Name = "shp" & VBA.Replace(rngChart.Parent.Name, " ", "") 
    End With 
End With 
End Sub
```